# Vector conversion from c++ to java

Tags: java, c++, vector, type-conversion

I have the following code in c++, trying to convert it to java code

The code snippets below shows what I've tried, but its not working

```cpp
C++
vector<vector<string>> ans;
ans.push_back(vector<string>());
for(int k = i, sum = 0; k < n && sum < l[j] ; ++k) {
        sum += (int) w[k].size();
        ans.back().push_back(w[k]);
```

```java
Java
static Vector<Vector<String>> ans = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
ans.add(new Vector());
for(int k = i, sum = 0; k < n && sum < l[j] ; ++k) {
        sum += (int) w[k].length();
        ans.add(w[k]);
```

```
ans.lastElement().add(w[k]); fixes it
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? It doesn't compile? It throws an exception? The result isn't expected?

Comment: managed to fix it. the last line should be ans.get(j).add(w[k]);

Comment: @SharhadBashar Then supply an answer to your own question - or remove the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be more specific about what is not working. At the first glance, instead of `ans.add(w[k]);`, try `ans.lastElement().add(w[k]);`. Notice how in your c++ code you have `ans.back().push_back(w[k]);`, not `ans.push_back(w[k]);`